# Android Kotlin - getPackageInfo is deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin

```
protected fun isPackageInstalled(packageName: String?): Boolean {
    try {
        application.packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName!!, 0)
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

getPackageInfo is deprecated, what to do instead?